# How to disable Explorer.exe for given user?

Tags: windows, windows-registry, boot

I know the shell registry key to disable it but I don't understand how to disable for specific user. Consider the situation where administrator cannot login user account but want to change user explorer.exe with some other program like iexplore.exe

Comment: You would probably need to write code to do this.  (Basic idea: change the shell to your application, then your application can decide whether to launch explorer.exe, iexplore.exe, or something else, based on the user account.)

Comment: Thats a brillian idea. but I read something about loading ntuser.dat to regedit hive. If user is not there ntuser is not there. I Want to do that

Comment: What exactly do you want? Do you want to prevent the user from starting Explorer.exe? Or do you want Windows to start iexplorer.exe instead of Explorer.exe when the user logs in?

Comment: In want to change the value of shell in windows registry for specific user. Normally I can change explorer.exe to iexplore on my profile but I want to do for other specific user who hasn't logged on yet.

Comment: For a user who is not logged on right now, or for a user who has never logged on (a newly created user)? Also: which Windows Version?

Comment: xp/vista/7.. and for user never logged on

Comment: If the user has never logged on, they don't have a profile yet, so you can't modify it.  Your only options are to use the equivalent HKLM setting (affecting everyone) or to log the user in once ahead of time.  Or you could modify the default hive, affecting all new users.

Comment: So can u suggest some batch script or vbs script to do that. I know with %username% in cmd i can get logged in username but i dont know complex script. Can you write that script in answer please

Comment: Werner's answer is better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'ld suggest that you use group policies. Microsoft has a [web page](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731758.aspx) how to edit multiple local group policy. One option is to create a group policy for all non-admin users. Another option is to create a group policy for each individual user. You might find it interesting looking at all the possibilities group policies give you.

Under `Configuration\Administrative Templates\System` you might be interested in `Run only allowed Windows applications`, `Don't run specified Windows applications` and  `Custom User Interface`. Group Policy Editor gives you a detailled description for every option.