# Stop IE from being started from a URL shortcut

Tags: windows, security, internet-explorer, group-policy

This question is similar to [How to disable Explorer.exe for given user?](https://superuser.com/questions/589422/how-to-disable-explorer-exe-for-given-user), but with a key difference: I've already blocked IE, mostly.

In Group Policy I have added iexplore.exe to the list of disallowed Windows applications, but have found that users can create a shortcut to a URL and click this, and it'll open Internet Explorer.

The iexplore.exe process is started, not from the users session, but apparently from the DCOM service:

[image: IExplore.exe is running when it shouldn't]

Any ideas how to catch this workaround and squelch it?

This fix needs to work on a Zero Client host server which has multiple simultaneous users, many of whom are allowed internet, and some of whom aren't, as well as on any other single-user workstations these users log into.

Comment: Blacklist the IE folder via [SRP](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb457006.aspx) and GP?

Comment: try to asign those url shortcuts to open with no Application or to just unasign them from IE. I don't know if this is possible but it may help you to see the problem from another View

Comment: konqui, that's a good idea and I was thinking about it earlier today. Haven't figured out how that would be applied yet. I'll report back once I've dug a little deeper.

Comment: What about blocking Internet Explorer system-wide? Would that work for you?

Comment: and31415: No. The point isn't to prevent IE only, it's to block internet. A few users have installed FF or Chrome, and I don't really mind. But the Internet-blocked users do not have install capability to put alternatives on. Because Group Policy can specify disallowed programs per-user, I've used this to block IE, and therefore internet, access on a per user, per session basis.

Answer (score 1):

The ideal solution would be to block IE completely, or even uninstall it, though this may have side effects (and it seems you have already tried it).

To answer the titular question of disabling IE running from URL shortcuts, you want to reassign the handlers for `http` and probably `https` (the [protocol handlers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/aa767914%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)) to something else, or even no application at all. This will also affect any other place run might try to "run" a URL, such as from the run dialog or start menu.

These can be found both per-user and per-machine, and is pulled from a combination of the two into [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724475%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). You probably want to override both the machine and user keys.

It may still be possible for a user to manually reset their own handler - so you may need to set the permissions on the key to disallow the user, and also the parent keys so they can't reset the permissions.

With all these caveats, properly disabling IE is the better way to go. But if you wanted to disable the shortcut-launch, this is how.

Comment: As noted in the latter portion of the OP, uninstalling IE is not an option because there are simultaneously on this system people with and without allowed internet access. Any block or restriction must be within the individual user session and must not interact negatively with any other logged on user.

I'll check out the handlers. My Exchange server decided today was a good day to have a fit, so this particular project is pushed off for the moment.

Comment: @music2myear It seems like the real solution is to set up a software firewall preventing those users from accessing the internet (similar to parental controls), rather than blocking the browser.