# How do I hide Windows Explorer on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, taskbar

I have a problem, I would like to hide my windows explorer from my taskbar.

Could you please explain to me how to do it.
I mean not by unpin the taskbar. But hide the contents of all My Computer (Drive C and D). 
Any suggestion would be appreciate.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: By "hide it from the tasbar", do you mean remove it from the taskbar, hide it so it can't be found from/by the taskbar, or hide it using a process initiated from the taskbar?

Comment: No, I mean not by unpin the taskbar, but hiding the contents of the Computer. so that the guest cannot find our folder @fixer1234

Comment: Your question is too vague. Please describe a computer in which you have "hidden" (as you put it) Windows Explorer.

Comment: So basically you want to disable a guest from using Windows Explorer at all? You could set up a Guest/non-admin account, and then see what all you can configure with Group Policy. Lots of options there, may fit your bill, not sure if you can disable all access though. Also this answer may give you leads: https://superuser.com/questions/589422/how-to-disable-explorer-exe-for-given-user

Answer (score 1):

Right click on the icon, then click "Unpin from taskbar".

To restore it, start Explorer, then click its icon, and click "Pin to taskbar".

Update: opening was updated with more clarification, here is the answer:

[Here](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/show-hide-a-drive-in-windows) is a guide on how to hide drive icons from "This Computer" page.

For C drive, you cannot use the first method, also keep in mind that Group Policy is not available if you are running Windows 7 Home Premium or below.

Comment: No, I mean not by unpin the taskbar, but hiding the contents of the Computer

Comment: @DeniYulianti I updated my answer.